# [javascript]-Regex code to input the text field not allowing to start with 0, but allow 0 and should not allow characters +,-,

Tags: javascript, regex

See, I'm looking for a regex code where a text field should only accept these

1. only positive whole numbers
2. can allow 0
3. should not allow +,-,.

it should not match: 0345, 7. , 7+ , +7 , .7 , -7 , 7- , ..7

**it must not accept:** 1. + 2. - 3. .

NB: I don't want keypress functions, I'm looking for the regex

Comment: You mean `+` `-` `.` only or include `(` and `)`.

Comment: it shouldn't accept + - .

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NaTDIO/1.

Comment: Thanks! but what about excludingthe  other 3 characters I mentioned.

Comment: They are not allowed here. How do you understand "excluding"?

Comment: I understand this, but it aint working for me, those 3 characters is accepted again. I wont mind if you make it complex

Comment: Did you see the demo? How do you test for acceptance?

Comment: Yes sir, I saw the demo. but it aint working for me..could you please suggest another method?

Comment: @JohnRoshan if it doesn't work for you, then you are doing something wrong. This regex is correct and will match exactly what you want. I added few more samples: https://regex101.com/r/NaTDIO/2 it shows that it does work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help! let me see what's wrong then. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Will this be of any assistance

```
$re = '/([1]\d+)/';
$str = '0123';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Now for the JavaScript equivalent

```
const regex = /([1]\d+)/g;
const str = `0123`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a regular expression.

Comment: Your code just searches for matches, it doesn't test if the whole string matches. So it will allow non-matching strings in between. I also don't understand why you have `[1]` in it. Where does the question say that the digit `1` has to appear in each match?